# php count с условием

Tags: php

```
 <?php foreach ($offers as $offer): ?>  
 <?php echo count($offer->users); ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Показывает количество строк users в offer

Но мне нужно еще показать количество users, в которых поля mybl и blist равны 0, в том же offer.

Это возможно?

Comment: запихните такие значения в отдельный массив и подсчитайте пототм в нем количество элементов.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь функцией `array_reduce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это возможно, конечно:

```php
foreach ($offers as $offer) {
    $userCount = 0;
    $userBlistCount = 0;
    foreach ($offer->users as $user) {
        $userCount++;
        if ($user["mybl"] == 0 && $user["blist"] == 0) {
            $userBlistCount++;
        }
    }

    echo '$userCount = ', $userCount, "<br>", '$userBlistCount = ', $userBlistCount, "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Более красивое решение через count(array_filter(...